# How to automatically resize/crop images in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins, size

I am novel to WordPress and I am creating a site that contains a bunch of images. I have a gallery with several images of different sizes, is there a way to automatically resize/crop images via pluggin or code such that the gallery will contain images all of the same size?

Here is a link - http://3d5.975.myftpupload.com/portfolio/tribeca/

I have searched online and the solutions I found are manually crop the images or style in CSS (which will distort the image if they are not the same aspect ratio). Maybe the better question is once an image is uploaded is there a way to automatically change the size or create a bunch of sizes such that all the images are the same size?

Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

When you upload any image from WordPress media uploader,it always make the 3 different size images (**thumbnail-150x150, medium-300x300 and large-1024x1024**) along with he original image.

However If you want to add more image sizes, you can do the following

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_theme_setup' );
function wpdocs_theme_setup() {
    add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 300 ); // 300 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
    add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180, true ); // (cropped)
}
```

Read [more](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)